# Daemon vs process

Tags: linux, docker, nginx

I am very new to linux, so I can't quite understand the difference between daemon, foreground process and background process.

As I understand that:

- Daemon is simply a background process that runs in the background and has **init** as its parent process.
- Foreground process is a process that we simply invoke from the console.

Then if I run for example nginx inside a docker container with "daemon off" flag that means that nginx will be the foreground process running in the container's console?

Comment: Yyyyyyyyyyyyes.

Comment: Thanks)) Didn't think that I get everything right)

Answer (score 0):

### What is the problem exactly?

- Read [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached-vs-foreground).

  - `To start a container in detached mode, you use -d=true or just -d option.`
  - `In foreground mode (the default when -d is not specified), docker run can start the process in the container and attach the console to the process’s standard input, output, and standard error.`